# Capture query parameters in nginx rewrites

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I saw an nginx rewrite rule that captured the query parameters from the URL and applied the same query parameters to the rewritten URL. I can understand that in some circumstances it could/would be beneficial to capture the query parameters in the rewrite rule, but it seems to me that in this situation doing so is pointless.

The rewrite rule in question is as follows:

```
rewrite ^/users/(\d+)\.html(?:\?(.*))?$ /users/profile.php?id=$1&$2 last;
```

Is this pointless as I suspect? I believe that the following rewrite rule would have the same effect:

```
rewrite ^/users/(\d+)\.html$ /users/profile.php?id=$1 last;
```

Comment: simple rewrites can't alter the query parameters, they are saved in `$args` variable, the only thing this rewrite would catch is if there's an extension to the uri eg:`example.com/index.html/some/extension`

Answer (score 0):

The first rewrite won't work, `$2` will always be empty, even if there's a query string that's passed to the request,

your second rewrite is quite correct but I don't think it would preserve the query string, if you want to do that then you should append it by your self.

```
rewrite ^/users/(\d+)\.html$ /users/profile.php?id=$1&$query_string last;
```